# Migrating from SQL DMO to SQL SMO (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, smo, sqldmo

I am migrating the SQL DMO logic to a SQL SMO logic and I am not sure how to achieve the same functionality for a few of the attributes.
This is the DMO:

```
    oBCP = New SQLDMO.BulkCopy2
    With oBCP
        .ImportRowsPerBatch = ImportRowsPerBatch                 
        .DataFilePath = Path.Combine(gtSysTempDir, "file.dat")     
        .LogFilePath = Path.Combine(gtSysTempDir, "file.log")      
        .ErrorFilePath = Path.Combine(gtSysTempDir, "file.err")     
        .MaximumErrorsBeforeAbort = 1                   
        .DataFileType = SQLDMO.SQLDMO_DATAFILE_TYPE.SQLDMODataFile_TabDelimitedChar
    End With
```

This is the SMO so far:

```
    trans = New Transfer
    With trans
        .ImportRowsPerBatch = ImportRowsPerBatch                 
        .TargetDatabaseFilePath = Path.Combine(gtSysTempDir, "file.dat")     
        .TargetLogFilePath = Path.Combine(gtSysTempDir, "file.log")       
        '.ErrorFilePath = Path.Combine(gtSysTempDir, "file.err")     
        .MaximumErrorsBeforeAbort = 1                   
        .DataFileType = SQLDMO.SQLDMO_DATAFILE_TYPE.SQLDMODataFile_TabDelimitedChar
    End With
```

What are the equivalents, if they exist, of ImportRowsPerBatch (BatchSize?), ErrorFilePath, MaxErrorsBeforeAbort, and DataFileType?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Despite [what the MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms162159), `Transfer` is not actually the equivalent of `BulkCopy2`; it's intended for scripting/copying entire databases whereas `BulkCopy2` is only for bulk copying data. The settings don't correspond at all -- in particular, `Transfer.TargetDatabaseFilePath` is supposed to be the location of a database file, whereas `BulkCopy2.DataFilePath` is the location of the file where imported/exported data goes. *Some* bulk copy scenarios are handled by `Transfer`, but most aren't.

If you're not actually copying an entire database, you have several alternatives, none of which use SMO (which has no class for bulk copying as such):

- Directly invoking a [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188365) statement, which is probably what `BulkCopy2` does in the background (but I haven't verified this);
- Using the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy) class, which will require some extra code (but which also offers far more flexibility as the data to be imported can come from any source);
- Building a command line and invoking [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms162802).

Of these, `BULK INSERT` is the most straightforward.